# How to get IPv4 address from SOCKADDR structure?

Tags: windows, winapi, winsock, winsock2

I can't figure out how to get the actual IP v4 address (e. g. 192.168.1.1 or its corresponding packed form as a 32-bit integer) from the `Address` field of [IP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS_LH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iptypes/ns-iptypes-ip_adapter_unicast_address_lh) structure. I went down the rabbit hole of the linked lists and corresponding MSDN links, but `SOCKADDR` is where it cuts off. `SOCKADDR` is the generic data holder, it has to be cast to the IPv4 variant in order to obtain a structured view of the data.

Trouble is, I can't find which structure is the IPv4 mapping for `SOCKADDR`. Tried `in_addr`, getting garbage values.

```
auto pAddresses = static_cast<IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES*>(malloc(defaultBufferSize));
    ULONG outBufLen = defaultBufferSize;
    constexpr ULONG flags = GAA_FLAG_SKIP_ANYCAST | GAA_FLAG_SKIP_MULTICAST | GAA_FLAG_SKIP_DNS_SERVER | GAA_FLAG_SKIP_FRIENDLY_NAME;
    auto result = GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_INET /* Only IP v4 since no cameras use v6 yet */, flags, nullptr, pAddresses, &outBufLen);

    uint32_t ipV4Address = 0;

    // Iterating over the returned adapter info structures
    for (auto currentInterfaceInfo = pAddresses; currentInterfaceInfo != nullptr; currentInterfaceInfo = currentInterfaceInfo->Next)
    {
        if (currentInterfaceInfo->IfType != IF_TYPE_IEEE80211 || currentInterfaceInfo->Ipv4Enabled != 1 || currentInterfaceInfo->ReceiveOnly != 0)
            continue;

        if (currentInterfaceInfo->FirstUnicastAddress)
        {
            for (auto addressInfo = currentInterfaceInfo->FirstUnicastAddress; addressInfo != nullptr; addressInfo = currentInterfaceInfo->FirstUnicastAddress->Next)
            {
                if (!addressInfo->Address.lpSockaddr || addressInfo->Address.lpSockaddr->sa_family != AF_INET /* IP v4 */)
                    continue;

                auto ipv4AddrInfo = reinterpret_cast<in_addr*>(addressInfo->Address.lpSockaddr);
                                                     ^^^^????
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is `SOCKADDR_IN`

Comment: @RbMm: Bingo! And thank you. Post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a `SOCKADDR*`, look at its `sa_family` field to determine the address type.

- for an `AF_INET` address, typecast the `SOCKADDR*` to `SOCKADDR_IN*`, and then you can access its `sin_addr` field.
- for an `AF_INET6` address, typecast the `SOCKADDR*` to `SOCKADDR_IN6*` and then you can access its `sin6_addr` field.

```cpp
std::vector<BYTE> buffer(defaultBufferSize);
auto pAddresses = reinterpret_cast<IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES*>(buffer.data());
ULONG outBufLen = defaultBufferSize;

constexpr ULONG flags = GAA_FLAG_SKIP_ANYCAST | GAA_FLAG_SKIP_MULTICAST | GAA_FLAG_SKIP_DNS_SERVER | GAA_FLAG_SKIP_FRIENDLY_NAME;
auto result = GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_INET /* Only IP v4 since no cameras use v6 yet */, flags, nullptr, pAddresses, &outBufLen);

uint32_t ipV4Address = 0;

// Iterating over the returned adapter info structures
for (auto currentInterfaceInfo = pAddresses; currentInterfaceInfo != nullptr; currentInterfaceInfo = currentInterfaceInfo->Next)
{
    if (currentInterfaceInfo->IfType != IF_TYPE_IEEE80211 || currentInterfaceInfo->Ipv4Enabled != 1 || currentInterfaceInfo->ReceiveOnly != 0)
        continue;

    for (auto addressInfo = currentInterfaceInfo->FirstUnicastAddress; addressInfo != nullptr; addressInfo = addressInfo->Next)
    {
        if (!addressInfo->Address.lpSockaddr || addressInfo->Address.lpSockaddr->sa_family != AF_INET /* IP v4 */)
            continue;

        auto ipv4AddrInfo = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in*>(addressInfo->Address.lpSockaddr);
        // use ipv4AddrInfo->sin_addr as needed...
    }
}
```